# How to wrap a function call C++ to assign variables

Tags: c++, function, wrapper

Is there a way to have a function that executes a different function but carries out the same steps independent of the function?

This example would better portray what I mean:

```
ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
    printf("SQL Failed\n");
    DisplayError(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
}

ret = SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
    printf("SQL Failed\n");
    DisplayError(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
}
```

I can't think of a more general example other than my specific needs, but the common part here is that I am always checking if the return variable from an SQL function is an error, and then if it is, printing said error. I feel this would be better if it was possible to wrap the error checking in a `debug` mode, and strip it off in a `release` mode, but I don't know how to do it. I am hoping that there is an answer along the lines of

```
SQL(ret, SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env));
```

Where wrapping the entire call in a defined `SQL` function would call any sql function passed in, as well as assigning it to the variable so long as the return types are the same.

I have tried to come up with something such as

```
#define SQL(a, x) (a = x; if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(a)) { printf("SQL Failed\n"); DisplayError(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);})
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: You could try to implement this SQL function with a parameter that is a function. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-cpp/)

Comment: I don't know how to do that, different SQL functions that I need to call have variable amount of arguments and variable types of those arguments.

Comment: You use a simple function with no param, and when you call the function you use a lambda to wrap it around

Comment: @RaduSebastianLAZIN I've seen somewhere that this type of thing exsts where it was an OpenGL function and it was something like GL(X) and it called any passed in opengl function (x) but I can't find it or remember how.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass functions by copying or by const reference...

```
int MyFunction( const std::function<int(void)> & fn )
{
    return fn();
}

int MyFunction2( std::function<int(int)> fn )
{
    return fn(7);
}
```

and either pass a Lambda

```
MyFunction([]{ return SomeIntFunction(); });
```

or a reference to a static function

```
MyFunction(&StaticIntFunction);
```

or bind the function

```
MyFunction(std::bind(&Class::SomeIntFunction, classInstance));
```

Comment: I am trying the first one, but replacing `int` to `SQLRETURN` and I am getting an error `expression must be an lvalue or a function designator`

Comment: Don't forget the void keyword: std::function<SQLRETURN (void)>

Comment: @RaduSebastianLAZIN It's there. This is what I am trying: `SQL(&SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env));` - so calling the `a reference to a static function`

Comment: @404TeamNotFound Can you post the signature and call? It's hard to understand what you're doing just from the error.

Judging from 'not an lvalue', try the copy approach (without the const & )

Comment: I would recomend to read up on C++ lambdas, closures, functors

Comment: @RaduSebastianLAZIN Yeah i def will, also cnh003, I tried both and still the same error.

Comment: @404TeamNotFound In this case a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would be really helpful. Without that, I can merely point you to the keywords to check up on.

Comment: try it with a lambda: SQL([] { return SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env); });